# Incrementing excel formula by two

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with the following formula:

```
=('Forecast Workings'!T2+'Forecast Workings'!T3)/1000-4.6
=('Forecast Workings'!T4+'Forecast Workings'!T5)/1000-4.6
=('Forecast Workings'!T6+'Forecast Workings'!T7)/1000-4.6
```

How can I write this formula so that I can simply drag this down to fill in the rest of the values and that I get the value to increment by 2 each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
=sum(index('Forecast Workings'!T:T, (row(1:1)-1)*2+2), 
     index('Forecast Workings'!T:T, (row(1:1)-1)*2+3))/1000-4.6
```

Comment: Thanks Jeeped this is what I was looking for many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If your initial cell is in first row and you want to multiply you could use:

```
=(INDIRECT("Forecast Workings!T"&ROW()*2)+INDIRECT("Forecast Workings!T"&ROW()*2+1))/1000-4.6
```

Subtract value from `ROW()` if you are not in the first row.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a helper column, or use indirect and then use a mathematical approach on the formula row() to get the right return. as an example if you start this in row 2 and drag down this will increment by two. (assuming row one are titles)

```
=INDIRECT("'Forecast Workings'!T" &  (ROW()-1)*2)+INDIRECT("'Forecast Workings'!T" &  ((ROW()-1)*2)+1)/1000-4.6
```

I would also advise to check out the code of conduct, you would need to show what you have tried to solve this yourself and what did not work.